# Flutter Error: VM snapshot invalid and could not be inferred from settings. - When want to include Flutter module in android project

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-engine, flutter-module

Use this Option B in [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup) to include Flutter model.
The project starts, but as soon as it comes to initializing the FlutterEngine, this error is thrown.

```
2021-12-10 13:54:09.300 12446-12446/ua.silpo.android.mtest E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_data.cc(18)] VM snapshot invalid and could not be inferred from settings.
    2021-12-10 13:54:09.300 12446-12446/ua.silpo.android.mtest E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm.cc(267)] Could not set up VM data to bootstrap the VM from.
    2021-12-10 13:54:09.300 12446-12446/ua.silpo.android.mtest E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_lifecycle.cc(84)] Could not create Dart VM instance.
    2021-12-10 13:54:09.300 12446-12446/ua.silpo.android.mtest A/flutter: [FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(144)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.
    2021-12-10 13:54:09.489 12603-12603/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(144)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.
        '
    2021-12-10 13:54:09.490 12603-12603/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000002cdfd4  /data/app/ua.someApp.android.mtest-MaQO6akxb8zud-dIXl0K7w==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x2c6000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actions are the following and the solution:

- created Flutter module.
- used connection to android via [Option B](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup).
- since the project had no name: app,
  i wrote in gradle.properties -> `flutter.hostAppProjectName = myAppName`
- my settings.gradle looked like this

  rootProject.name = "mobileAndroid"
  include ': app'
  setBinding (new Binding ([gradle: this]))
  evaluate (new File (
  settingsDir.parentFile,
  './SuperApp_Frontend_Silpo/.android/include_flutter.groovy'
  ))

But the problem was that the project had its own buildTypes, so it was necessary to write

```
staging {
matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
}
```

in Flutter module build.gradle